# What type of curve does Photoshop's Curves use?

Tags: curves

I'm trying to figure out what kind of curve Photoshop's Curves interface uses. Here are some examples:

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to recreate the effect using D3.js and SVG. None of the [curves available in D3](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curves) (cubic basis spline, Catmull-Rom, etc.) fit. I have tried polynomial interpolation, but that tends to [introduce unnecessary wiggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) into the curve, as evidenced below:

[image]

I'm not too fluent in the concepts involved, but I have tried my hand at piecewise polynomial interpolation, which sounded pretty close to that, but with which I still have not had success.

I hope someone with more experience with these concepts, and hopefully with access to Adobe Photoshop or a similar app, can shed some light on the situation :)

Here is a sample input-output from the Photoshop curves interface:

[image]

## Update

Photoshop seems to be using **cubic splines**, [as implemented here](http://blog.ivank.net/interpolation-with-cubic-splines.html).

Note that it differs from what a *natural* spline is called in [D3-shape](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveNatural)

[image]

Comment: This has been discussed (I'm not sure what the answer is--there seems to be disagreement in the answers and comments) in [this stackoverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4356788/9234657)

Comment: I've seen that thread, which offers a few ideas: Catmull-Rom splines and natural cubic splines. I had tried the implementation of these from D3, and they did not seem to work as expected, (may have been a confusion of terms somewhere?), so I discounted them...

Comment: There are lots of different types of cubic splines, depending on how you choose the unknown derivatives at the specified points. It sounds like the solution you found is what's known as the *natural* cubic spline. You should consider posting your finding as an answer to the question.

Comment: @Rahul, thanks for the input! I've edited my question to include the difference between this particular implementation of the cubic spline and what a _natural_ cubic spline looks like, at least in the D3 library. Can you help me understand why it is that they look different in some cases, but overlap in others?

Comment: I guess it's because Photoshop is fitting a spline function $x_i\mapsto y_i$ while D3 is fitting a parametric curve defined by two functions $i\mapsto x_i, i\mapsto y_i$. If you include the coordinates of all the control points (the input/output values to the lower left of the graph) in one of the Photoshop screenshots, we can verify for sure.

Comment: P.S. That StackOverflow thread sure is full of a lot of amateur speculation.

Comment: I've added in the description an example of Photoshop Curves input -> output values.

Comment: You can try plugging in the values into [Timo Denk's cubic spline interpolation tool](https://tools.timodenk.com/cubic-spline-interpolation). Looks to me like it matches Photoshop's curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer seems to be [a cubic interpolating spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation).**

As to how to draw it using Bézier curves (i.e. an algorithm for determining the Bézier control points), I have moved tbat to [a separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678997/b%c3%a9zier-control-points-for-drawing-an-interpolating-cubic-spline-function?noredirect=1&lq=1).